# How to install pecl spidermonkey on CentOS 6

Tags: php, centos, pecl

Running the following command:

```
> sudo pecl install spidermonkey
```

I receive the following error:

```
...
... a bunch of successful checks ...
...
checking whether to enable spidermonkey support... yes, shared
configure: error: jsapi.h not found. Please reinstall libjs.
ERROR: `/var/tmp/spidermonkey/configure' failed
```

I attempted to remedy the problem by installing js-devel, which, after wrestling with various yum repositories, I finally did manually like so:

```
> wget http://pkgs.repoforge.org/js/js-1.60-1.el6.rf.x86_64.rpm
> wget http://pkgs.repoforge.org/js/js-devel-1.60-1.el6.rf.x86_64.rpm
> yum install js-1.60-1.el6.rf.x86_64.rpm
> yum install js-devel-1.60-1.el6.rf.x86_64.rpm
```

(Not sure why js-devel required js to be installed first ... but, it complained when I tried to install js-devel solo.)

Re-running the `pecl install`, I receive the same error. Is my understanding that the js-devel package contains the libjs stuff simply incorrect? Are there additional steps? Or, do I need to look elsewhere to get libjs?

ADDENDUM: I also tried removing the above packages (using yum) and installing these builds:

```
> wget http://puias.math.ias.edu/data/puias/6/x86_64/os/Addons/js-1.70-12.puias6.x86_64.rpm
> yum install js-1.70-12.puias6.x86_64.rpm
> wget http://puias.math.ias.edu/data/puias/6/x86_64/os/Addons/js-devel-1.70-12.puias6.x86_64.rpm
> yum install js-devel-1.70-12.puias6.x86_64.rpm
```

No dice. The command line js interpreter works perfectly. But, PECL yields the same error.

Answer (score 2):

While this doesn't address the problem of the package not installing correctly using the package manager, the steps in this article left me with spidermonkey functioning correctly in PHP:

http://devzone.zend.com/1480/using-javascript-in-php-with-pecl-and-spidermonkey/

This is a workaround, in my opinion. I'm assuming the PECL package installed through the pecl package manager is intended to *work correctly*. So, I'm still interested in other more qualified answers.